# Reload Static Bing Map Blazor Maui

Tags: .net, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

Trying to reload a static bing map with pushpins based on a button click in .net Maui Blazor but having some difficulty. I have been thinking I needed to call statehaschanged, but running into some blanks. Ideas? I would prefer to use the .net 7 map they released, but I would rather not change from Blazor, so static it is.

```
@page "/"
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Maps;

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div>
    <iframe width="500" height="400" frameborder="0" src=@bingMapURL scrolling="no">
     </iframe>
     <div style="white-space: nowrap; text-align: center; width: 500px; padding: 6px 0;">
        <a id="largeMapLink" target="_blank" href="https://www.bing.com/maps?cp=35.12552479342789~-89.8846435546875&amp;sty=r&amp;lvl=11&amp;FORM=MBEDLD">View Larger Map</a> &nbsp; | &nbsp;
        <a id="dirMapLink" target="_blank" href="https://www.bing.com/maps/directions?cp=35.12552479342789~-89.8846435546875&amp;sty=r&amp;lvl=11&amp;rtp=~pos.35.12552479342789_-89.8846435546875____&amp;FORM=MBEDLD">Get Directions</a>
    </div>
    
</div>

 <button
     onclick="GeneratePushpinsAndCreateMap"
 ></button>
<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code{
    string bingMapURL = "https://www.bing.com/maps/embed?h=400&w=500&cp=35.12552479342789~-89.8846435546875&lvl=11&typ=d&sty=r&src=SHELL&FORM=MBEDV8";

    public async Task GeneratePushpinsAndCreateMap()
    {
        try
        {
            // Generate 10 random pushpins
            var random = new Random();
            var randomPushpins = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                .Select(i => new { Latitude = 47.6 + (random.NextDouble() - 0.5) / 10, Longitude = -122.35 + (random.NextDouble() - 0.5) / 10, Label = (char)('A' + i) })
                .ToList();

            // Build the Bing Maps API call
            var bingMapUrl = "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Road/47.619048,-122.35384/15?mapSize=500,500";
            foreach (var pushpin in randomPushpins)
            {
                bingMapUrl += "&pp=" + pushpin.Latitude + "," + pushpin.Longitude + ";;" + pushpin.Label;
            }
            bingMapUrl = "&mapMetadata=1&o=xml&key=" + "Apa9h5v5oA1qTLyQ - oW4q7AQuHFsPg0lXr4gX8RQrV5Tx--5CsGL - UoQtGEx_8_v";

            StateHasChanged();


          
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle the exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you need to install the [Syncfusion.Blazor.Maps](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Blazor.Maps). This package contains the [Blazor Map Component](https://www.syncfusion.com/blazor-components/blazor-map?utm_source=nuget&utm_medium=listing&utm_campaign=blazor-maps-nuget) for `Blazor application`.

In addition, to raise the `onclick` events, you need to add `@` in front of the `onclick` events like below:

```
 <button
     @onclick="GeneratePushpinsAndCreateMap">
     GeneratePushpinsAndCreateMap
</button>

@code
{
     public async Task GeneratePushpinsAndCreateMap()
    {
    
       try
        {
            // Generate 10 random pushpins
            var random = new Random();
            var randomPushpins = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                .Select(i => new { Latitude = 47.6 + (random.NextDouble() - 0.5) / 10, Longitude = -122.35 + (random.NextDouble() - 0.5) / 10, Label = (char)('A' + i) })
                .ToList();

            // Build the Bing Maps API call
            var bingMapUrl = "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Road/47.619048,-122.35384/15?mapSize=500,500";
            foreach (var pushpin in randomPushpins)
            {
                bingMapUrl += "&pp=" + pushpin.Latitude + "," + pushpin.Longitude + ";;" + pushpin.Label;
            }
            bingMapUrl = "&mapMetadata=1&o=xml&key=" + "Apa9h5v5oA1qTLyQ - oW4q7AQuHFsPg0lXr4gX8RQrV5Tx--5CsGL - UoQtGEx_8_v";

            StateHasChanged();


          
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle the exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thank you for the directed response. Let me know if you likewise need a bit of research done. Cheers.

Comment: I have not heard from you for a couple of days. May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.